# Scanf the numbers into function in C

Tags: c, function, scanf

here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct note {
    int pitch;
    int velocity;
    int channel;  
} note;

int printnote(int pitch, int velocity, int channel);

int main() {
    int size = 100;
    note note;
    struct note *ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    printf("Input the values for the `pitch`, `velocity`, and `channel`\n");
    scanf("%d ％d %d", &note.pitch, &note.velocity, &note.channel);
    printnote(note.pitch, note.velocity, note.channel);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}

int printnote(pitch, velocity, channel) {
    printf("The MIDI Note is:\n");
    printf("Pitch -> %d\n", pitch);
    printf("velocity -> %d\n", velocity);
    printf("channel -> %d\n", channel);
    return 0;
};
```

When I run the code and type the numbers, it shows the wrong answers.
For example, I run the code, and it shows

```
Input the values for the `pitch`, `velocity`, and `channel`
5 5 5 
The MIDI Note is:
Pitch -> 5
velocity -> 0
channel -> -429762432
```

The three numbers should be the same as the input numbers.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `％d` with full-width `％` is invalid as format specifier. Use `%d` instead. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Even i got same observation as @MikeCAT the second  %d looks different than other two `scanf("%d ％d %d", &note.pitch, &note.velocity, &note.channel);` one more thing is why is the memory allocated and freed, though the `malloc` is done for wrong size

Comment: @sravs Why do you say the allocation size is wrong? `ptr` is not used other than allocation and freeing, so I don't think there is any correct size to allocate there. (or maybe zero is correct because it isn't used)

Comment: @MikeCAT `malloc(size * sizeof(int));` should be `malloc(size * sizeof(struct note));` if he really wants to use for storing multiple records

Comment: @sravs Ah, I forgot that `ptr` has type `struct note *`. `malloc(size * sizeof(*ptr));` may be better.

Comment: @MikeCAT: I would not close this answer as a simple typo because it is informative for many readers who are unaware of Unicode traps and pitfalls. This particular typo is probably more common in Japan and China and would not be so easy to spot if all 3 `%` characters had been mistyped as `scanf("％d ％d ％d", ...)`. As a matter of fact % is indistinguishable from ％ in the font used for comments.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle typo in your `scanf()` conversion string:

```
scanf("%d ％d %d", &note.pitch, &note.velocity, &note.channel);
```

You used the unicode full width percent sign `％` (\uff05) instead of the ASCII `%` character. `scanf` does not recognise this as a conversion specifier and tries to match the byte sequence used to encode `％`, (0xEF 0xBC 0x85 in UTF-8) and fails thus only converting the first input into `note.pitch` and leaving `note.velocity` and `note.channel` uninitialized, returning `1`. Note how `％` looks different from `%` in the fixed font used for code, but identical in the font used for this text: ％ % *％* *%* **％** **%**.

Just replace `％` with the correct character:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &note.pitch, &note.velocity, &note.channel);
```

Also note these remarks:

- `size` and `ptr` are not used in `main()`,
- you should check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input. This check would have helped find the error,
- the prototype in the definition of `printnote` is incorrect: the argument types are missing,
- the `;` after the `}` is useless,
- using the same identifier `note` for the variable and its type is confusing.

Here is modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct note {
    int pitch;
    int velocity;
    int channel;  
} note;

void printnote(int pitch, int velocity, int channel);

int main() {
    note note1;

    printf("Input the values for the `pitch`, `velocity`, and `channel`\n");
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &note1.pitch, &note1.velocity, &note1.channel) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printnote(note1.pitch, note1.velocity, note1.channel);
    return 0;
}

void printnote(int pitch, int velocity, int channel) {
    printf("The MIDI Note is:\n");
    printf("pitch -> %d\n", pitch);
    printf("velocity -> %d\n", velocity);
    printf("channel -> %d\n", channel);
}
```

Comment: "ignores it, only converting 2 inputs" is incorrect. It will expect that the input matches `％`, finding it doesn't match and stop there. Data is read only into `note.pitch`, and `note.velocity` and `note.channel` will be left uninitialized.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Good catch! I am not thinking clearly... time to go home before the curfew! Answer amended.